# Column '' does not allow nulls. But there is no null value

Tags: .net, vb.net, datatable, datarow, data-corruption

I am doing this on VB.net:

I have a datatable named as **'dt'** whose structure is like this:

**4 columns:
'OptionId'
'ChoiceId'
'Choice'
'Description'**

Datatable dt has roughly 800 records.

I am passing it to a function:

```
Process(dt,"VehicleChoice;VehicleChoice", "Choice;Description", "Choice;Description", "ChoiceId;ChoiceId")

Public Sub Process(ByRef dt As DataTable, ByVal TableNames As String, ByVal ColumnNames As String, ByVal TableColumnNames As String, ByVal IdentityColumns As String)
    Dim aTableNames As String() = TableNames.Split(";")
    Dim aColumnNames As String() = ColumnNames.Split(";")
    Dim aTableColumnNames As String() = TableColumnNames.Split(";")
    Dim aIdentityColumns As String() = IdentityColumns.Split(";")

    ' remove readonly from columns
     For Each Column As String In aTableColumnNames
         dt.Columns(Column).ReadOnly = False
         dt.Columns(Column).MaxLength = -1
     Next

    ' ProcessFurther
     For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
         For i As Integer = 0 To aTableColumnNames.Length - 1
             ProcessFurther(row(aTableColumnNames(i)), aTableNames(i), aColumnNames(i), (row(aIdentityColumns(i)))
         Next
     Next
End Sub

Public Function ProcessFurther(ByRef OriginalValue As Object, ByVal TableName As String, ByVal ColumnName As String, ByVal IdentityValue As Integer) As String
     Dim OriginalValue = Some value which is not even related with any of these codes, but uses the params to retrieve this value.
     Return OriginalValue
End Function
```

So the function here is plain simple, I don't know why I am getting this error: (From Log4Net)

### *** Error Message ***

Column 'OptionId' does not allow nulls.

### *** Error Source ***

System.Data

### *** Error Target Site ***

Void CheckNullable(System.Data.DataRow)

### *** Stack Trace ***

```
at System.Data.DataColumn.CheckNullable(DataRow row) 
at System.Data.DataColumn.CheckColumnConstraint(DataRow row, DataRowAction action) 
at System.Data.DataTable.RaiseRowChanging(DataRowChangeEventArgs args, DataRow eRow, DataRowAction eAction, Boolean fireEvent) 
at System.Data.DataTable.SetNewRecordWorker(DataRow row, Int32 proposedRecord, DataRowAction action, Boolean isInMerge, Boolean suppressEnsurePropertyChanged, Int32 position, Boolean fireEvent, Exception& deferredException) 
at System.Data.DataRow.EndEdit() 
at System.Data.DataRow.set_Item(DataColumn column, Object value) 
at ProcessFurther(DataTable& dt, String TableNames, String ColumnNames, String TableColumnNames, String IdentityColumns) in the For Loop (Stack trace has Line No of that For Loop, not the actual function.)
```

Biggest confusion for me here is, **why/how is 'OptionId' even a problem here.** It's not even involved during our processing, though it is just part of the datatable. This makes absolutely no sense to me at all. Also, this happens at random. Like it might happen for 1-2 minutes. And it will be gone for like few hours and will again behave the same in a while. There is no pattern for it, data is still the same when it errors/when it doesn't error out.

Please help if anyone might have a clue on this, Thanks

Comment: First things first, get rid of the `ByRef` on the parameter. You're not assigning anything to that parameter inside the method so there can't possibly be a reason to declare it `ByRef`.

Answer (score 1):

I think I see where the issue is and it's no shock to me that the problem is that you are using `ByRef` when you shouldn't be.  Stop using `ByRef` and learn what it actually does, then use it only when it is specifically required.  Your `ProcessFurther` method look like this:

```
Public Function ProcessFurther(ByRef OriginalValue As Object,
                               ByVal TableName As String,
                               ByVal ColumnName As String,
                               ByVal IdentityValue As Integer) As String
```

and here is how you call it:

```
ProcessFurther(row(aTableColumnNames(i)),
               aTableNames(i),
               aColumnNames(i),
               row(aIdentityColumns(i)))
```

By declaring that parameter `ByRef`, you are specifically saying whatever is assigned to that parameter inside the method should be assigned back to whatever you passed in in the first place.  What you passed in in the first place was `row(aTableColumnNames(i))` and therefore, when you assign to the parameter on the first line of the method, you are assigning to that specified column of the `DataRow`.  Presumably what you're assigning is `DBNull.Value` and that's why you get an error telling you that the column doesn't accept NULL.

When I made the comment on your question about removing `ByRef` from the parameter, I was actually talking about the `dt` parameter of the `Process` method.  That one's not hurting you but it shouldn't be there anyway.  At that stage, I didn't notice that you were using it elsewhere too.  In this case, it is hurting you.  DO NOT use `ByRef` unless you specifically need to.  If you don't know when you need to, learn.  This is not VB6, where you use it to stop large objects being copied.  In VB.NET, any object that is an instance of a class is a reference type and will therefore not be copied when passing by value anyway.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It makes sense of not using the ByRef in the Process function. AndAlso, from ProcessFurther function, I am returning something else and not OriginalValue, which would make sense of using the ByRef there. I am still confused why the error is pointing to 'OptionId', we are not trying to assign the DB.NullValue to that column anyway even if we were based on what you said. That is strange to me. :(

Comment: Have you debugged your code? It seems to me that you must not have. Based on the exception, you are calling `ProcessFurther(row(aTableColumnNames(i)), aTableNames(i), aColumnNames(i), (row(aIdentityColumns(i)))` when `aTableColumnNames(i)` is "OptionId" and then, when you assign to `OriginalValue` inside the method, the value that you have explicitly omitted and claimed is irrelevant is actual `DBNull.Value` and is extremely relevant. Debug the code properly and that should become obvious.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time and advice. I appreciate it. However if you notice, I am explicity sending "VehicleChoice;VehicleChoice" as arguments to TableNames parameter in the Process() function. And aTableColumnNames is just a string array after spliting TableNames. So logically, it doesn't make sense for OptionId to appear on the error. With DBNULL.Value logic, our error should have looked like this instead: Column "Choice" does not allow nulls. 

Another strange thing that happened today was I saw this on the Stack trace. Column 'AnotherColumn' (part of dt) does not allow nulls...

Comment: Sorry aTableColumnNames is just a string array after spliting TableColumnNames and I am sending "Choice;Description" as argument to the function. 
Clearly something is off!! Not sure what though.

Comment: DEBUG THE CODE!!  Do you know how to set a breakpoint and step through code?  If not, learn now.  That's how you track down these things.  Sure, looking at inputs and reading code is a first step but, if nothing jumps out at you, the next step is debugging.  Then you can see exactly what is happening and exactly what data is in use at every single step of the code, including immediately before the exception is thrown.

Comment: hahaha. Of course I know how to debug the code and I am debugging it right now as well...Data is perfect and I am digging deeper and deeper, but not able to understand what's happening on production. Like I said on live, it appears sometimes only. Code is same, data is same. I will let you know if I find out anything. If nothing works out, I will have to add some loggings at every step to see what's happening. Thanks again!!

Comment: OK, sorry. I probably don't recall some of what you posted days ago and didn't go back and read it again.

Comment: Hey, i was able to find out the problem for this. This had nothing to do with using ByRef.

Problem was the way the datatable was being created and used.

The datatable 'dt' that is used in the first line was coming from Application Cache, but was being modified on every request, which was the root cause of the problem.

So the full workflow in simpler terms was something like this:

Dim dt = Cache.Get(Of DataTable)("CacheKey").Value
If dt Is Nothing Then 
//Build the datatable and Set the Cache.
Cache.Set("CacheKey", dt)
End If

Rest is the same.

Comment: The problem was when the 'dt' (coming from cache) was modified, the in-memory Cache was also modified. So yeah two separate users accessing the same function around the same time (concurrent requests) is causing this to happen because the Cache was modified by the one request and the other request didn't like it whilst still working on the same Cache object. I replicated this using JMeter to hit the function with 500 concurrent threads. So one thing to learn here is never modify the Cache for every request. This actually defeated the purpose of using Cache in the first place.